# How can I improve my geolocation query so not to take 8mins of cpu time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, geolocation

I use php and mysql to query about 2G of data, for an individual accounts geogrpahy data sum up this against the long and lat, I then use the results to send to google to heat map

This takes ages... up to 8mins for the calculation

```
SELECT SUM(`Geography`.`Orders`)AS `weight`,
       `location`.`latitude`,
       `location`.`longitude`
 FROM `mobile`.`Geography`
INNER JOIN `mobile`.`location` ON (`Geography`.`City` = `location`.`city`)
AND (`Geography`.`Country` = `location`.`country`)
WHERE (`Geography`.`Advertiser ID` = $mid)
GROUP BY `Geography`.`City`;
```

Is there a better way in doing this or an alternative all together to do this? the $mid is for the php varialbe to replace with an accounts information

Comment: is your table is indexed?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the following indexes:  `Geography(AdvertiserId, City, Country, Orders)` and `Location(city, latitude, longitude)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select sum(g.Orders) as weight,
   (select l.latitude from mobile.location l where 
    (g.City = l.city) and
    (g.Country = l.country) limit 1
    ) as latitude,
   (select l.longitude from mobile.location l where 
    (g.City = l.city) and
    (g.Country = l.country) limit 1
    ) as longitude
   from mobile.Geography g
   WHERE (g.Advertiser ID = $mid)
GROUP BY g.City;
```